# jQuery automate multiple scripts for multiple divs

Tags: jquery

in jQuery I always encounter alot of double work. I mean, I write the same thing for different divs.

I have the following code:

```
var about = $('#about').offset().top - parseFloat($('#about').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
var education = $('#education').offset().top - parseFloat($('#education').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
var work = $('#work').offset().top - parseFloat($('#work').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
```

and

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= about) {
        // if so, ad the fixed class
        $('#nav li').removeClass('current');
        $('.ab_about').addClass('current');
    } else {
        // otherwise remove it
        $('.ab_about').removeClass('current');
    }

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= education) {
        // if so, ad the fixed class
        $('#nav li').removeClass('current');
        $('.ab_education').addClass('current');
    } else {
        // otherwise remove it
        $('.ab_education').removeClass('current');
    }

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= work) {
        // if so, ad the fixed class
        $('#nav li').removeClass('current');
        $('.ab_work').addClass('current');
    } else {
        // otherwise remove it
        $('.ab_work').removeClass('current');
    }

});
```

You can say that if I have 20 of those items, it's gonna be a very long script :P
Any idea on how to automate things and make it smaller. I tried something with the .each method, but that was a dead end for me.

Ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u can just create a simple plugin and assign that plugin to those divs like:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function(options){
   var $this = $(this);
   var $navli = $(options.navli);
   var $abClass = $(options.abClass);
   var offset = $this.offset().top - parseFloat($this.css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
   $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        // what the y position of the scroll is
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        // whether that's below the form
        if (y >= offset) {
            // if so, ad the fixed class
            $navli.removeClass('current');
            $abClass.addClass('current');
        } else {
            // otherwise remove it
            $abClass.removeClass('current');
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#about').myplugin({'navli': '#nav li', 'abClass': '.ab_about'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're trying to do, but from the looks of it, you probably shouldn't use JS to achieve it.

Anyhow, the best way to simplify it would be to create a jQuery plugin. Something like this:

```
$.fn.fixStuff = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        return $this.offset().top - parseFloat( $this.css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0) );
    });
};

$('#about, #edutcation, #work').fixStuff();
```

Comment: What do you suggest I should use?

Comment: Like I said. I have no idea what your trying to do, but the JS seems kinda hackish. I don't know if it's possible in your situation, but JS hacks should always be the last option. I try to use CSS as much as I can. However, you might find this jQuery plugin useful: http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: You're right and I also checked that plugin indeed. What I was trying to do: When I scroll down the page (with mousewheel), I wanted to dynamically highlight the current menu-item in relationship to it's anchor div. In order to do that, I had to know the top offset of a div. If the user scrolls to the next div, the next menu-item should be highlighted.